# php curl get 2 row tabel

Tags: php, curl, preg-match

How get 2 rows in a table; get IP Address : Port ?

```
$ch = curl_init ("http://gatherproxy.com/sockslist");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$page = curl_exec($ch);

preg_match('#<table[^>]*>(.+?)</table>#is', $page, $ip);

$result = $ip[0];
echo $result;
```

Comment: no, use HTML parsers for this instead

Comment: What is the output you need ?

Comment: i need output IP ADDRESS:PORT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a HTML parser like [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) , but if you really need a regex to parse the ip and port, you can use:

```
$ch = curl_init ("http://gatherproxy.com/sockslist");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$page = curl_exec($ch);

preg_match_all('/document\.write\(\'(.*?)\'\).*?document\.write\(\'(.*?)\'\)/sim', $page, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++) {
    echo "PROXY: ".$matches[1][$i]. ":".$matches[2][$i]."<br>";
}
```

Comment: if im not use simplehtmldom,
only php not add plugin or another plugin,
how if only using php ??

Comment: my answer doesn't include `simplehtmldom` it was just an advice. Have you tried my code?